# SimpleDateFormat not giving correct date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse the date from a given String. My input string is 2017-08-11, which represents Aug 11th 2017 (Basically yyyy-mm-dd format)

However if I run

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse("2017-08-11") 
I get Wed Jan 11 00:08:00 GMT 2017
```

Why is this? I have created a test program at: http://ideone.com/dHe0ZA

Answer (score 2):

M (capital M) represents month and m (small m) represents minute in java.
So the format you have specified is wrong.

Try

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2017-08-11")
```

You can see more details about the formats [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).